# Namespace error ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I am getting error- Message from application: undefined local variable or method `api' for main:Object (NameError), /app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb:1:in`'

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: "json" } do
  devise_for :users
  resources :items
end
```

my folders are (app/controllers/api/items)
In api folder first one is base_contoller whhich has these:

base_Controller.rb

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
```

Please help to resolve. I tried changing the api to Api in routes folder then it gives error saying "this name is not suitable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following variant?

```
module Api
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    # code here
  end
end
```

It should work with `namespace :api etc...` from your `routes.rb`

I think version with class `Api::BaseController` doesn't works because it is `Qualified Constant` according to the [official guide about constants lookup in rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) and has another resolution algorithm. It would be helpful to checkout mentioned link